# Get value double value from string using RegEx in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace, double

I have following string value which is coming from database.

```
str=  ">= 5.0 years"
```

Now from this string i want the value of double number (5.0). How can i get this value from this string?

Can any one tell me how to get the value like 5.0 from above string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this pattern:

**PATTERN**

```
\d+?.\d+
```

I'm not sure how to use regex in Visual Basic, however this C# code should help you:

**C# code**

```
string regex = @"\d+?.\d+";

string myString = ">= 5.0 years";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(myString, regex);

foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as simple as it is: `[\d.]+` matches the floating point number

Comment: Wouldn't it match something like 5.0.0.0.0.0.0 as well?

Comment: Of course, but based on the input given, the number would be selected as well