# is there any function to get numeric , double value from string from xml using linq c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Have Tried this but need in linq c#

> [Get value double value from string using RegEx in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280428/get-value-double-value-from-string-using-regex-in-vb-net)

```
 <Root>
    <Amount>
        <Rate> INR to USD  3.0245</Rate>
    </Amount>
    <Amount>
        <Rate> Dong to INR  5.201454</Rate>
    </Amount>
    </Root>

 string xml = @"<Root>
                        <Amount>
                            <Rate> INR to USD  3.0245</Rate>
                        </Amount>
                        <Amount>
                            <Rate> Dong to INR  5.201454</Rate>
                        </Amount>
                        </Root>";

            XDocument Doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var list = Doc.Descendants("Amount").Select(y => new
            {
                Rate = (string)y.Element("Rate")
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

need Output : 3.0245, 5.201454 using linq c#

Comment: What have you tried so far? At least you should have some code that de-serializes the xml or reads the xml. So the question comes don to how do I extract a substring from a string matching a pattern.

Comment: Need in linq? Your problem can´t be solved with linq as y<ou need a **pattern**, not an approach on iterating elements. Anyway show some code which you have so far.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - He can use linq to read the values of `Rate` and then the `select` will use regex to extract the value

Comment: @GiladGreen Yeah I know, I supposed his actual question was on how to parse that string where linq won´t add *any* value.

Comment: with above code i am getting value as it is  not applied any thing to get double value or numeric value , is there any way to get this double value with linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output it seems all you need is the numbers themselves so I look for the `<Rate>` descendants. Then for each of them use regex (regex was adapted to case out of this question: [Extract decimal from string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11061592/6400526)) to find the number and return it:

```
string xml = @"<Root>
               <Amount>
                   <Rate> INR to USD  3.0245</Rate>
               </Amount>
               <Amount>
                   <Rate> Dong to INR  5.201454</Rate>
               </Amount>
               </Root>";

XDocument Doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var list = Doc.Descendants("Rate")
              .Select(y => Convert.ToDouble(Regex.Match(y.Value, @"\d+(?:\.\d+)?").Value))
              .ToList();
```

---

In the case that you have `<Rate>` elements with no numbers or if a single one might have more than 1 number use:

```
 var list = Doc.Descendants("Rate")
               .SelectMany(y => Regex.Matches(y.Value, @"\d+(?:\.\d+)?").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value))
               .Select(y => Convert.ToDouble(y))
               .ToList();
```

Comment: ,@Stephan Bauer,@HimBromBeere  thanks for your quick Ans, suppose pattern of rate  description will change , will have to change  pattern again ?

Comment: @yashfale - The pattern above extracts only the number part of the text so it doesn't matter. However if you have more than 1 number or no numbers at all you should change the linq to support that

Answer (score 0):

You need a regex for parsing the string:

```
XDocument Doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var r = new Regex(@".*(\d+[\.,]?\d+)");
var list = Doc.Descendants("Amount").Select(y => new
{
    Rate = r.Matches[0]((string)y.Element("Rate").Value)
});

var rate = Convert.ToDouble(list.First().Rate);
```

The regex will match both notations using a colon and a dot as decimal-seperator. When you need only the dot the regx is simplified to `@".*(\d+[\.]?\d+)"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse it without using a regex, you could try this as well.
This code relies on the fact that the numerical rate value is at the end of the string and has a space `' '` in front of it.
So the **text after the last space** is parsed as a `double`. The `CultureInfo` is set to `en` to ensure that the decimal point is recognized correctly.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
double[] values = doc.Root
    .Descendants("Rate")
    .Select( elem => double.Parse(elem.Value.Substring(elem.Value.LastIndexOf(' ')),CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("en")))
    .ToArray ();
```

Comment: can u explain me this code , i just  want to avoid Reagex in case my rate description pattern will change then regex will be a problematic to me

Comment: I added an explanation. But if the pattern is likely to change, a regex is the better solution, since you could make it configurable.